# how to add directory in package.json to publish in npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, npm

When I try to publish a module in npm repository it is not taking lib folder. I added it in package.json file as below but it is not taking that lib folder. Lib folder contains files that are used by module.

```
{
    "name": "sample",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "sample.js",
    "directories":{
        "lib": "/lib"
    } 
}
```

Comment: try removing the / from lib so it becomes `"lib": "lib"`

Answer (score 4):

remove the / from lib, so your package.json becomes

```
{
    "name": "sample",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "sample.js",
    "directories":{
        "lib": "lib"
    } 
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply,well i tried it and it publishing in npm but when i install it from npm lib folder is not available in module

Comment: is the lib folder installed in your node_modules/sample (or whatever the name of your module is)

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by not available

Comment: lib folder which is there in my module while i  publishing in npm, is not there after i install that module in my pc

Comment: the folder needs to be committed to your git repository... have you done `git add --all lib/` and committed it?

Comment: i got answer, i have to mention it in files like this  "files": [
    "Readme.md",
    "app.js",
    "lib/",
    "images/"
  ]

Answer (score 2):

Add the files to `package.json`

```
{
  "files": [ "lib" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `files` or `directories` ensure the path or paths are specified as expected. Rather than `/lib` you probably want `./lib`. Verify the files and folders you want to publish are not being ignored by a `.npmignore` or `.gitignore` dotfile in the `lib` directory of your project. Also, if there's a separate `package.json` file in `lib` you'll wan to check that too.

For more information see:

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#directories